# Efficient date-based lookup function in R

Tags: datetime, r

Right now this function takes an excessively long time to run, please let me know how to make it more efficient.

`lunarCal` is 144x7 and the `dput` for it is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6c3d252dfd6bd2a72f36ca95e42eeec0).

Here's the code:

```
if(!require(pacman)) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(lubridate)
cat("Please make sure that birthday inputs are in YYYY-MM-DD format")

lunarCal             <- readRDS("data/lunarCal.RDS")

eastern.profile <- function(birthday){
    good                 <- is.na.POSIXlt(birthday)
    if(!(good)){birthday <- strptime(birthday, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "Asia/Chongqing")}
    ind                  <- (lunarCal$START_DATE <= birthday) & (lunarCal$END_DATE >= birthday)
    temp                 <- subset(lunarCal, ind)
    return(temp)
}
```

Here's an example of its non-vectorized usage:

```
eastern.profile("1975-01-01")
   YEAR START_DATE   END_DATE ANIMAL ELEMENT ASPECT                                   PERSONALITY
75 1974 1974-01-23 1975-02-10  Tiger    Wood      + Imagination, creativity, idealism, compassion
```

When I run it I'm using `sapply` but it's still slow. I've got a data set with 250,000 dates I'm applying it to and it took over 15 minutes.
We can simulate the data set to run this function on with

```
dat <- as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("1900/1/1"), as.Date("2040/1/1"), "days"))
dat <- rbind(dat,dat,dat,dat)
```

Comment: Hello! Please don't make changes to the original post once it has been reviewed, as that invalidates the current answers. Please see our meta side on [performing iterative reviews](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) for more information!

Comment: Hi @syb0rg! OK, sorry about that, but there's only 1 current answer and it returns an error (in part) because of the fact that I didn't put `as.data.frame()` around the first line of my suggested simulation of the data. So I'm changing it to make the current answer valid...

Comment: Ah, I see.  I only saw you edited the code after an answer was given and thought it would invalidate the answer.  Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the function `findInterval`. It is vectorized so it can treat all your dates in a single (fast) call. Your code should look something like this:

```
eastern.profile <- function(birthday) {
   bad <- !is.na.POSIXlt(birthday)
   birthday[bad] <- strptime(birthday[bad], format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "Asia/Chongqing")
   ind <- findInterval(birthday, lunarCal$START_DATE)
   cbind(birthday = birthday, lunarCal[ind, ])
}
```

Note that I was not able to test because of some issues I had with your data. So it may need some tweaks.

Comment: Thanks much! I'll mark this as the solution for `findInterval`. Part of the problem may be that we need to put `as.data.frame` around the first line of the simulated data. However, even after doing that and sorting the data non-decreasingly it still throws an error. `Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(x) : 'origin' must be supplied` I know this error is usually solved by setting an origin of the Unix epoch, but that doesn't seem to working here.